# Story about space soldiers controlling clones remotely

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about 10-15 years ago, and believe it was an 80s-90s book. The premise was that soldiers/space marines were remotely controlled, and if they died, their operators woke up in a vat back on their base ship. The book ended with the main character being betrayed, and most of the clones vats being destroyed. I think it was around 300-400 pages long?

The most notable point of the book was that the soldiers were considered suicide soldiers, designed for suicide missions, as death didn’t matter.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Check if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SendInTheClones . This looks promising:  "In the Clone Series (Clone Republic, Rogue Clone, Clone Alliance, Clone Elite, and Clone Betrayal) all the enlisted men in every branch of the military are clones, and very disposable ones at that. The only strategy that the military (namely the marines, seeing as that is the perspective) really have is (you guessed it) sending in the clones. "

Comment: Sounds more like [The Flesh](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flesh) or Gangers than Star Wars clones.